# Is there a fast way to remove items from a list based on there position?

Tags: python, list

This is my first post so I will most likely do something wrong. I am wondering if there is a faster way to remove items from a list based on their position. I am relatively new to python so I most likely have overlooked a faster way.

```
Stack3 = (Cards[0],Cards[1],Cards[2])
while Count < 3:
    Cards.pop(0)
    Count += 1
Count = 0
```

This is what my current code is. As you can see, I am just removing the first item from the list many times over. This seems very messy and unorganized to me. I would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: have a look at [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Comment: This question is not about slicing isn't it?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist `Stack3` is a tuple, but `Cards` might be the list that OP is asking about

Comment: @DeepSpace : you are correct! removed that part of my comment.

Comment: also might as well use sth like: `Cards[0:3]`

Answer (score 3):

Removing elements from a list while looping is not a good practice. A better way to do it is to use a `list comprehension`:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
indices_to_remove = [3,4,1]

lst = [elem for index,elem in enumerate(lst) if index not in indices_to_remove]
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
[1, 3, 6, 7]
```